# Swagger Routing error in '/' Application (Error 404)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, swagger

I am creating a WEB API for Framework 4.7.2 which connects to swagger.
I already have a similar page done in WCF, the API should connect to page:
http://localhost:39536/index.html?url=//swagger.json (In API of course)
when I debug I receive the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> The resource cannot be found.
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

I checked similar questions done previously but they do not work.
my RouteConfig:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and my WebApiConfig:

public static class WebApiConfig
{
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
// Web API configuration and services

```
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

My SwaggerConfig:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
          .EnableSwagger(c => c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "TradingDataTranslationService"))
          .EnableSwaggerUi();
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The files you've shared look good. However, I noticed that in your SwaggerConfig class, there is no mention of the following assembly line. Here is an example for your reference:

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace RMDataManager
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
```